# Your account is locked. Try again in 1 minute

Tags: login

I am using an M2 Mac mini with Sonoma, and whenever I restart or shut down my Mac, I get "Your account is locked. Try again in 1 minute" message on the login screen, and that is without making any mistakes. Every time I have to wait 1 minute before logging into my account.

I have talked to Customer support and they told me to reinstall macOS which is the last thing I want to do. I have tried making a dummy user, and that one doesn't get locked.

Does anyone know how to solve that issue or remove the login screen altogether?

Comment: Have you tried changing the password?

Comment: Thanks a lot benwiggy!
I have just tried to change my password 2 times and a second time when I changed it back to being empty space like before I don't have that message anymore.

Comment: I would not use an empty password. That's very unsafe. It's possible that something has gone wrong in the setup, which may actually require starting again from scratch. You just need to Erase the Content and Settings In System Settings > General. Then go through setup, and restore everything from your backup.

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue. Support not any help as yet.Started at 3 minutes and now after one week, it’s now at 5 minutes. Have stopped login items, created another admin account. New account boots up in seconds without delay. Did this three times just because and then tried my main admin account again. Still 5 minute lock. Turned off AVG programs and rebooted. Still same issue. That’s all for today and I will update in a few days or sooner if I find a solution!

Comment: Did you do the action stated in the first comment? @DustyPirate